# my very simple script does not work in asp mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new in jquery and I just want test a simple script code in mvc. I did not changed  default code of home controller  Index view just I added a button like this

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="click"/>
```

and at the end of index view I add a script code as follow:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        alert('jQuery Tutorial');
    });
});
```

but when I run the project and click on the button it does not show me alarm. I really get confused because I have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in layout file but after running project in inspect of chrome  I see it does not recognized `$`. how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `<script>` definition is after the bundle registration, that #button1 does actually exist, and that you aren't having other issues with the bundle.  Sometimes the bundle renders scripts out of order so there is another JS error, and that trickles down and causes an issue with this script.

Comment: Thank you very much, by moving   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) from the end of body to head of _layout the  problem is solved because you mentioned that Make sure that <script> definition is after the bundle registration.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your App_Start folder BundleConfig.cs to make sure your bundles are set up.

such as

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");`

Comment: I did not change it and it is like the statement you write